# Texture Low Poly or High Poly Mesh?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking

What difference does it make if I texture the low-poly model directly or texture the high-poly model and bake the result onto the low-poly model?
 What i want to say is in which cases i should bake the textures from the high poly mesh to the low poly mesh ?

Comment: what do you mean by "texture"?

Comment: In addition to @moonboots comment - clearly it depends on your model and its details. "Texturing" is a bit more than just slapping some colors on a model. Think of Normal Textures and what they do. If you just want to skip the baking process, why bother with a high-poly model at all? Feel free to use the edit link below your question to add missing infos and maybe some images as well.

Comment: Yes please give an example